# React native payment gateway for UAE

Tags: react-native, payment-gateway

I am searching for a good payment gateway plugin for UAE as stripe and Paypal is not available in UAE, Please help me to find out payment gateway for UAE?

Comment: Payfort, paytabs

Answer (score -1):

You can use original in-app purchase functionality.

Please check `https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap`

Comment: Is Apple take a 30%?

Comment: https://www.mobiloud.com/help/knowledge-base/what-are-apple-and-googles-fees-and-revenue-share-percentage-on-in-app-purchases-and-subscriptions/

Comment: It's not allowed to use other payment method in apple store

Comment: We can't use any other payment method like Payfort in  apple store?